# 4x4 slide puzzle BATCH

Tags: batch-file

How can I make this more efficient and how can I keep the grid from breaking when you make a move. The first group of code is the setup for the batch file, the second group is part of the grid generation (I find to be to long), and the third group of code is the movement and display.

```
@echo off
title Slide Puzzle && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && set default= %
set pos=16
set loop=1
```

Here is the 15th box in the 4x4 grid. The previous ones are not as long but the same. It first generates a random number between 1 and 15 and checks if its been used already. After this it tests if it is a single digit, if it is a single digit it adds a space in front of it so that it doesn't break the grid.

Is there a way I can shorten this?

```
:R15
set /a R15=%random% %% 15 +1
if %R15%==%R1% goto R15
if %R15%==%R2% goto R15
if %R15%==%R3% goto R15
if %R15%==%R4% goto R15
if %R15%==%R5% goto R15
if %R15%==%R6% goto R15
if %R15%==%R7% goto R15
if %R15%==%R8% goto R15
if %R15%==%R9% goto R15
if %R15%==%R10% goto R15
if %R15%==%R11% goto R15
if %R15%==%R12% goto R15
if %R15%==%R13% goto R15
if %R15%==%R14% goto R15
set slide15=%R15%
if %R15% lss 10 set slide15= %R15%
```

This is where the numbers are displayed in a 4x4 grid

```
:display
cls
echo  ____ ____ ____ ____
echo ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|
echo ^| %slide1% ^| %slide2% ^| %slide3% ^| %slide4% ^|
echo ^|____^|____^|____^|____^|
echo ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|
echo ^| %slide5% ^| %slide6% ^| %slide7% ^| %slide8% ^|
echo ^|____^|____^|____^|____^|
echo ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|
echo ^| %slide9% ^| %slide10% ^| %slide11% ^| %slide12% ^|
echo ^|____^|____^|____^|____^|
echo ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|    ^|
echo ^| %slide13% ^| %slide14% ^| %slide15% ^| %slide16%  ^|
echo ^|____^|____^|____^|____^|
```

Everything below this is how the numbers move around side to side and up and down. The problem here is that if you move a single digit number it removes one of the spaces making the grid uneven and distorted.

```
:movew
if %pos% GEQ 13 goto display
set /a helper=%pos% + 4
set /a slide%pos%=!slide%helper%!
set slide%helper%=%default%
set /a pos=%pos% + 4
goto display
:movea
if %pos% == 4 goto display
if %pos% == 8 goto display
if %pos% == 12 goto display
if %pos% == 16 goto display
set /a helper=%pos% + 1
set /a slide%pos%=!slide%helper%!
set slide%helper%=%default%
set /a pos=%pos% + 1
goto display
:moves
if %pos% LEQ 4 goto display
set /a helper=%pos% - 4
set /a slide%pos%=!slide%helper%!
set slide%helper%=%default%
set /a pos=%pos% - 4
goto display
:moved
if %pos% == 1 goto display
if %pos% == 5 goto display
if %pos% == 9 goto display
if %pos% == 13 goto display
set /a helper=%pos% - 1
set /a slide%pos%=!slide%helper%!
set slide%helper%=%default%
set /a pos=%pos% - 1
goto display
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The problem here is that if you move a single digit number it removes
>   one of the spaces making the grid uneven and distorted.*

You should be moving constant width label strings, not numbers.

I can think of multiple strategies for eliminating any spaces in the labels:

1) Use hexadecimal notation: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F

2) Use 0 prefixes: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15
*Note that you cannot use such labels as numbers because 0 prefixed numbers are treated as octal, and 08 and 09 are invalid octal numbers.*

3) Use Letters: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O

But there should be no problem manipulating labels with spaces.

> *It first generates a random number between 1 and 15 and checks if its been used already. After this it tests if it is a single digit, if it
>   is a single digit it adds a space in front of it so that it doesn't
>   break the grid.*
>
> *Is there a way I can shorten this?*

Your strategy of randomly selecting a number between 1 and 15 until you get one that hasn't been used yet is very inefficient. Theoretically you could wait a long time before you succeed. With only 15 tiles, the wait will likely not be long, but if you had hundreds of selections to make, then you could be waiting for a loonnnnggggg time.

Much better to define a string of unused tiles, and then randomly select a position within the string. Assign the selected tile, and then remove the selected tile from the unused string.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cls

:: Define string of equal width tile labels
set "tiles= 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9101112131415"

:: Iterate and assign in reverse order so %%N matches the number of available unused tiles
for /l %%N in (15 -1 1) do (

  %= Randomly select position of an unused tile, and compute the postion of next tile =%
  set /a "selected=!random!%%%%N*2,next=selected+2"

  %= Extract and assign the selected tile label =%
  for %%A in (!selected!) do (
    set "slide%%N=!tiles:~%%A,2!"

    %= Remove the selected tile from the list of unused tiles =%
    for %%B in (!next!) do set "tiles=!tiles:~0,%%A!!tiles:~%%B!
  )
)

:: Show results
set slide
```

## Warning

I hope you realize that if you randomly arrange the tiles, you have a 50:50 chance of having an unsolvable puzzle. [It is possible to compute if an arrangement is solvable](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mdr/teaching/modules04/java2/TilesSolvability.html). If your arrangement is not solvable, then you should be able to swap a pair of tiles to get a solvable puzzle.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response.

Answer (score 2):

```
:R15
set /a R15=%random% %% 15 +1
for /l %%n in (1,1,14) do if !R%%n! equ %R15% goto R15
set slide15=%R15%
if %R15% lss 10 set slide15= %R15%
```

Comment: This was helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
:set_all_r
for /L %%n in (1,1,16) do set /a R%%n=0
set /a count=1
:set_r
set /a r!count!=%random% %% 15 + 1
for /L %%n in (1,1,14) do if %%n neq %count% if !r%%n! equ !r%count%! goto set_r
set slide%count%=!r%count%!
if %count% lss 10 set "slide%count%= !r%count%!"
set /a count+=1
if %count% neq 16 goto set_r
set "slide16=  "
```

This routine should set R* and slide*
The first `for` sets R* to zero; non-zero values are assigned later.

For each `count`, limited to 15 (ie until incrementing it results in `16`), set a random value and check that none of the R* has this value. If one is found having the same value, re-choose the random value otherwise increment the count until the limit is reached.

Since the last value to be assigned is R15 (R16 = 0, slide16="  ", an empty square) then only R1..14 need be checked.

> ((Please do **NOT** accept this answer as correct - it's merely a development on that presented by @PaulHoule ))